# Inputs a string or list of int, returns a list with no duplicates next to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input: a string of characters or a list of integers
Output: a list of elements with no repeats next to each other in the same order as input

i.e. ('aabbcccdddaaa') = ('a','b','c','d','a')

```
def no_near_dups(a):
    L = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(str(a)):
        if a[i] == a[i+1]:
            i += 1
            continue
        L.append(a[i])
        i += 1
    L.append(a[i])
    return L
```

I am receiving the error: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: note: your code has typos.

Answer (score 0):

you are receiving that error because on line `a[i] == a[i+1]` index is out from bounds when i equals to `len(str(a))-1` . that's why change your code to:

```
def no_near_dups(a):
    L = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(str(a))-1:
        if a[i] == a[i+1]:
            i += 1
            continue
        L.append(a[i])
        i += 1
    L.append(a[i])
    return L
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like :

```
>>> a='aabbcccdddaaa'
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> "".join([i for i,k in groupby(a)])
'abcda'
```

Answer (score -1):

len starts counting from 1--> and onwards but index starts from 0  --> onwards
so there is an off by one index out of range error

```
def no_near_dups(a):
L = []
i = 0
while i < len(str(a)-1): **add a minus one**
    if a[i]) == a[i+1]):
        i += 1
        continue
    L.append(a[i])
    i += 1
L.append(a[i])
return L
```

Comment: it wouldn't work! `len(str(a)-1)` -1 must be outside from len function like `len(str(a))-1`